# Full-dimensional convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry

Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ is convex and $n>2$.

Suppose also that for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ there exist $x,y\in A$ and $j\neq i$ such that $x_i>y_i$ and $y_j>x_j$.

**Question:** Does $A$ contain $n$ linearly independent elements?

Comment: Thank you. I had in mind $n>2$ - sorry for not mentioning it in the original post.

Comment: In fact, let me restrict the question further by requiring $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n_+$

Comment: What is the range of $j$?

Comment: $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right, this $A$ does not contain $n$ linearly independent points. Let us consider $n=3$, and let $A$ be the segment connecting the points $x=(1,1,0)$ and $y=(0,0,1)$. If $i=1$ or $2$, then let $j=3$, and let $x$ and $y$ be the ones above. If $i=3$, let $j=1$ and switch $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Since coordinates should be positive, I would take those points shifted by the vector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: My bad, I (wrongly) interpreted $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ as the non-negative numbers.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I changed $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ to $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$ in the statement of the question